Cannot install lvgl package using pip on linux
I am running Ubuntu 22.04. I am unable to install the package "lvgl" from pip. I run the command python -m pip install lvgl and it fails, appearing to be an issue with not being able to source a directory for an import statement in the setup.py. I have also tried installing the package manually by cloning the git here: https://github.com/kdschlosser/lv_cpython using git clone --recurse-submodules <git url>, installing all dependencies and running python -m pip install . inside a venv. Still no dice. Oddly, however, this package installs perfectly normally on windows running the same python3.11+ versions.
Here is trace when tyring to build using python -m pip install lvlg:
python -m pip install lvgl
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting lvgl
  Using cached lvgl-0.1.1b0.tar.gz (3.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/pi/Desktop/lvglTesting/testTwo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/pi/Desktop/lvglTesting/testTwo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/home/pi/Desktop/lvglTesting/testTwo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-73aiy93g/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 334, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-73aiy93g/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 304, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-73aiy93g/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 320, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'builder'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


any help would be greatly appreciated!

I might try upgrading/reinstalling pip and setuptools but that is just a shot in the dark.

@JonSG Thanks, unfortunately I have done both of those with no luck. Also tried many different versions of all dependencies and python

https://github.com/kdschlosser/lv_cpython/issues/14

@phd I published that issue.

@shortCircuit77 My advice is to put it in the question.

Oddly, however, this package installs perfectly normally on windows running the same python3.11+ versions - PyPi has a whl for windows, so no compilation is performed. The source distribution on PyPi seems broken (builder directory is missing, but needed for import from setup.py) - what was the error when you tried to install from github?

I managed to dive a bit deeper but still got an error. Reported at https://github.com/kdschlosser/lv_cpython/issues/15

@phd Thanks for following it down further. I got a little furth myself, and got a successful build on Ubuntu. The issue seems to lie with the Git commit to convert everything to submodules. I switched to commit 8d4c1ef. And got a successful build.

@FlyingTeller Thanks for the information. That makes a lot more sense now. I did not know that compilation wasn't performed when installing from the whl. You're correct on the builder directory. Phd linked the error I was seeing in his comment above. My reply back to him indicates my assumptions as to how it's failing. Havent dug down that hole too deep yet though.

https://github.com/kdschlosser/lv_cpython/issues/14#issuecomment-2561555380
